# Installing software for 14.04 from 16.04 or newer repositories

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, updates, screen

I want to install GNU screen. In 14.04 LTS, latest available in main repos is `4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704-9` [[click me]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/screen) and trusty-backports gives me `4.2.1-2~ubuntu14.04.1` [[click me]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-backports/screen). Because of [CVE-2017-5618](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-5618/) I want to install anything newer than 4.5.0.

In the artful repos I can get `4.6.1-1` [[click me]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/screen)

I understand from reading [UbuntuBackports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) that, basically, I can't get my hands on anything newer than `4.2.1-2~ubuntu14.04.1` while living within 14.04 LTS. Is this true? (installing manually with .deb is not preferred)

Comment: from my reading of https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-5618.html  you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-5618.html you are not affected.

> Package Source: screen (LP Ubuntu Debian) Upstream:   released (4.5.0-3)
>
> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr):   not-affected
>
> Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus):  not-affected
>
> Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus):   not-affected (4.5.0-3)

I do not know if you can install anything newer than 4.2.1-2~ubuntu14.04.1 , but if the backports team says no, then it is unlikely you can upgrade as I would assume they know that status best.

You could try pinning and / or installing from source code. Pinning is not as easy as it sounds and can break your system (I generally advise pinning to advanced users only)

There are examples of pinning and how to use pinning here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

In your case, skipping from 14.04 to 16.04 or higher, and considering backports team advises against upgrading to a higher version, I would advise against it as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret that. The description starts with "GNU screen before 4.5.1..." and it's unclear if it's something strictly limited to 4.5.0-3 or an issue that's been in there for earlier version up until 4.5.1. What's your intreperation? +1 for showing me Pinning, TIL - thank you. Not something I will consider unless desperate and confident but it does directly answer my question.

Comment: That is the (archived) ubuntu security notice. https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/ . If you search the "USN" (Ubuntu Security Notice) for "CVE-2017-5618" it leads to https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-5618.html . If you read that page, it states that "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr): not-affected" so your version of screen is not affected by that bug and thus Ubuntu did not release a fix.